# jQuery dialog jumps to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery in order to create a custom popUp similar to a tutorial/tip for the end user (who can be on Chrome OR any other browser).  However as you can see in the below image, the divs that contain my code have a large top which pushes my code down. While using Chrome's developer tools, I notice it would take -591px to have the popup where I want so I used the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" />
  <script>
    function myFunction() {

        $(function () {
            $("#something").dialog();
        });

        $("#something").dialog({
            top:-591
        });
    }
    </script>

    <div id="something"  style="resize:both; display:none; background-color:yellow; height: 200px; width:200px;">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed.</p>
</div>
```

I tried several answers from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247486/jquery-ui-dialog-dragging-issues) but they didn't work. Also, I noticed when I comment out the first script line (jquery-2.1.11.min.js) it stops working, so it might have to do with that jQuery version?

Here is the screenshot from Chrome's Dev Tools:[image]

Comment: You have some error in `console`? What is that?

Comment: Why are you including jQuery UI twice?

Comment: He has added it to `<link>` and it should have been `CSS`

Comment: @j08691 I had referenced this site...http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Uncaught ReferenceError: dialog is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have added `js` again instead of adding `CSS`

Change it to `jquery-ui.css`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/bb4mceb2/)**

Comment: Sure.. Happy Coding.. :)